# Extracting values for tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, data-visualization

This is a continuation from my previous posts on the bubble chart I have been struggling to make. I have achieved my desired effect by adapting Chris Tufts's code:

https://blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/347e2b0aeed51d7dc56fde40b08e5fcd

However, when I attempt to add tooltip, I'm unable to extract the original value of BMI and Race(In the code, BMI = size and Race = group) This is because .data is calling nodes instead of the original data. Does anyone know how to point the tooltip to grab the right values?

I know that I should define group and size in create_node function such as the following, but I received an unexpected var token error.

```
function create_nodes(data,node_counter) {
  var i = cs.indexOf(data[node_counter].group),
  var z = cs.data[node_counter].group,
  var s = cs.data[node_counter].size,
      r = Math.sqrt((i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random())) * maxRadius,
      d = {
        cluster: i,
        z,
        s,
        radius: radiusScale(data[node_counter].size)*1.5,
        text: data[node_counter].text,
        x: Math.cos(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + width / 2 + Math.random(),
        y: Math.sin(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + height / 2 + Math.random()
      }

  if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) clusters[i] = d;
   console.log(d);
  return d;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create the `size` property the same way you created the `group` one:

```
size: data[node_counter].size,
```

By the way, you have a syntax error (you're missing the colon) in the `group` one, which should be:

```
group: data[node_counter].group,
```

Here is your updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/5802f23a0bd1c4a3f94f95eded56bc97/dc36321d0d4bb7db2a44246f9330f22099276524

---

PS: as a friendly advice, you don't need that cumbersome function. Just change the `data` array and pass it directly to the layout.